# CUDALink with Nvidia GTX770

Tags: cudalink, gpu

We are running a *Windows 7* machine with  *Nvidia GTX 770*.

According to this reference [GPU Hardware](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Reference.html#1803279895):

*CUDA* for *Mathematica 9* is not supported on that hardware.

Is there any way to get it running?

```
CUDAQ[]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
CUDAInformation[]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[8]:= CUDAInformation::syslibfld: CUDA failed to load system
> libraries.  Refer to CUDALink System Requirements for system requirements. >>
> ```

```
CUDADriverVersion[]
```

> ```
> "320.57"
> ```

Comment: Did you take a look here? http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html. If I remember correctly, not all version of drivers are cuda compatible..

Comment: Sorry for asking about the obvious, but did you download and install the latest CUDA driver (not general graphics driver) for your card from NVIDIA?  If my memory serves me well (it doesn't always...) I needed to do that when I set up CUDALink on Windows last time.  But that was a long time ago.

Comment: Yes I've set up everything. CUDA works fine in Visual Studio... but not in Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

There is a post that I [posted](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/184830?p_p_auth=mre7FQF8) in Mathematica that may be helpfull.  There is a problem with the way to install visual studio and the C Compiler. Remove the CUDA driver. Follow with the installation of  Visual Studio 2012 NOT the 2013. Then re install the drivers.

I suggest you print the following code and post the results here

```
Unprotect["`*"]
ClearAll["`*"];
Needs["CUDALink`"]
Needs["OpenCLLink`"]
Needs["SymbolicC`"]
OpenCLQ[]
CUDAQ[]
CCompilers[]
CUDADriverVersion[]
CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]
$CUDADeviceCount
SystemInformation[]
```